# how to substr the value of the array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, substr

I need to get the first two characters out of:

```
$node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value']; //there are like 200 - 300 characters
```

I try to go with:

```
$bodyemail = substr($node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value'], 0, 2);
```

and it doesn't work.
Then I need to do something like this:

```
if ($bodyemail == 'ok') {
    drupal_set_message ('done');
}
else {
    drupal_set_message ('not done');
}
```

I know that its an array... and `substr` works with string. but I really don't know how to do it in another way. Google didn't help.

Comment: Why does it not work? What does `var_dump($node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value'])` give you?

Comment: Please regard a print_r($node->field_email_body).

Comment: `$node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value']` is an array? `gettype($node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value']);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code looks fine.

i suggest setting that position of your array to its own variable, then try and substr that. then you can echo/log both and see what they are set to.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help and time.
the problem was in my code... at the last line with 'drupal_set_message' I forgot to put ')' and thought that my issue was with 'substr'. now its fine.

```
function driver_mailer_node_presave($node) { 
if ($node->type == 'mailhandler_source'){
drupal_set_message ('mailhandler node: ' .print_r($node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value'], true));
$string = $node->field_email_body['und'][0]['value'];
$bodyemail = substr($string, 0, 10);
drupal_set_message (print_r($bodyemail, true));
}
}
```